# Can't find file on stackblitz Angular project

Tags: angular, stackblitz

I generated service in my 'services' directory and import it. I'm getting this error:

```
Import error, can't find file:
./services/timer-service.service
```

app.component.ts

```
import { TimerService } from  './services/timer.service';
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-subject-queue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no service exist on path './services/timer-service.service'. You must have rename service file name to './services/timer.service'

You need to remove old reference from app.module.

Below line to be removed and providers list will be updated accordingly.

```
import { TimerServiceService } from './services/timer-service.service';
```